# Can't disable example app on Web2Py

Tags: python, web2py

I've set up an instance of Web2Py on a hosted server and in the administrative interface, I've disabled the example app but it's still accessible. For example, (see what I did there?) if I type the address *myserver.com/examples/template_examples/beautify* then Web2Py happily dumps all sorts of nasty bits about my server onto the page for God and everybody to look at.

How do I make a *Web2Py installed application* inactive without deleting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are behind a proxy. If so, web2py probably sees the request as local, and the "disable" functionality doesn't affect local requests.

A simple alternative is to add something like the following to the top of the first model file (e.g., db.py) of the app:

```
raise HTTP(503, '<html><body>Down for maintenance</body></html>')
```

Comment: This makes sense but (since you answered my other question apparently related to proxy as well) this seems like a bandaid for a symptom of the real problem. I can print `{{=request.client}}` and I get my public ip address instead of *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*. Does that mean Web2Py should be properly evaluating `request.islocal()`?

Comment: I just checked and *request.env.remote_addr = "127.0.0.1"* and *request.is_local = "True"* . This may be a 4 year old issue: http://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/detail?id=582

Comment: First, the above method of disabling an app is not a bandaid but a standard method. The admin "disable" function didn't even exist for the first few years of web2py's existence. It is simply a convenience method, and in many cases, not the preferred approach (e.g., it allows no flexibility regarding the message displayed).

Comment: Regarding the `is_local` issue, relying on x-forwarded-for is not safe, as that header can be spoofed. If running behind a proxy, you simply should not depend on the `is_local` attribute. If you have an alternative solution, please propose it on the web2py [developers list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py-developers/kkBvSzX4wO8), where this is actively being discussed.

Comment: Note, it won't help with the "disable" function, but for other uses of `request.is_local`, you can simply set the value manually in your app code based on where the app is deployed (e.g., using a server environment variable, or simply manually specifying the value).

Comment: The 503 error of course works perfectly. I also set `request.is_local=False` in *main.py* BUT after reading discussion on the dev list, I wonder if that should be in *db.py*? Will *main.py* ever reset *is_local* without *db.py* (or anything copied from *model.py*) getting to set it back to False? AND If that ends up in *model.py* what will be the effect if someone sets it False in *db.py* but forgets to in another model?

Comment: I would recommend against hacking the framework modules. Anyway, I think main.py is the only place the framework sets request.is_local, so if you alter it there, it should stay that way (for all apps).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to change the last element in the path name to something that isn't a valid Python identifier.  Web2py internally represents views, models, apps and other constructs using python objects, and if you give something a name that isn't a valid identifier, web2py will pas over it.

For example, change `beautify` to `beautify.IGNORE` and see what happens.

I can't recall which objects have this effect immediately and which require the web2py server process to restart.  I think (not sure) app name changes require a restart while views, controller etc. do not.